# Extracting and creating .jar archive containing aux / aux.*

Tags: windows, jar, java

I am attempting to extract the contents of a .jar that contains a file named `aux.class` using jar.exe from JDK 7u25 on Windows 7.

```
jar.exe xf C:\Path\to\file.jar
```

An exception is thrown, and jar.exe fails to perform the operation:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: aux.class <The system cannot find the file specified>
```

The underlying issue is that `aux` is a reserved name in Windows; is there any way to extract a .jar containing either aux or aux.* using the JDK? How would I go about creating a .jar containing a file named aux or aux.*?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you are mentioning `aux.class` in the command line. Are you?

Comment: Any additional arguments to the command above specify files to be extracted from the .jar. The generalized command I provided should [extract all the files in the archive](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/unpack.html). Is there a way to specify output file names? That would probably solve the issue, but this isn't discussed in the documentation.

Comment: Just grab all files. Seriously, why not?

Comment: I am attempting to extract **all** files in the .jar; jar.exe is failing because aux is a reserved file name in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

A JAR is just a ZIP file with a manifest and a specific ordering of the content files. You can extract any file from a Jar using an unzip tool. To extract the AUX file, use the "rename" capability that's in most zip tools, or "extract to..."